# Is there a R function that finds parameters to arbitrary models?

Tags: r, model-fitting

I am trying to fit the model y=c0*log(c1*x+1) where y and x are my data and c0 and c1 are parameters for the model. I know that the "fit" command in Matlab can do this, but I am trying to do this in R. I was wondering if anyone could offer suggestions on a function that can accomplish this.

```
model <- y ~ c0*log(c1*x + 1)
```

I am expecting a logarithmic curve.

Comment: you probably want to fit using `glm`

Answer (score 1):

This is a nonlinear regression problem where y equals the right hand side plus an error.

To fit such a model use `nls` in base R (see `?nls` for more info) or any of a number of other nonlinear regression functions.  See https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html . Subject to certain caveats `nls` will find the parameters that minimize the sum of the squares of the errors given the model and starting values.

```
# create test data
set.seed(123)
c0 <- c1 <- 1
x <- 1:10
y <- c0 * log(c1 * x + 1) + rnorm(10)/10

# fit model to the data
fm <- nls(y ~ c0 * log(c1 * x + 1), start = list(c0 = mean(y), c1 = 1))
fm
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ c0 * log(c1 * x + 1)
   data: parent.frame()
    c0     c1 
0.9207 1.2210 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.07622

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.887e-06
```

To graphically assess the fit:

```
plot(y ~ x, pch = 20)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try `fit.models` (check out: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fit.models/fit.models.pdf). Best of luck!